# Element is not clickable after zoom

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver, webdriverwait

all
I fetch element by selenium and python:

```
driver.get(url)    
el = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('mycssselector')[0]
el.click()
```

It's ok!
But next, I found some time the page is too lage, so I zoom in the page before click:

```
driver.get(url)    
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='85%'")
el = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('mycssselector')[0]
el.click()
```

But this time, I got error message:

```
element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (1626, 120)
```

Is there any way to do cilck after modify zoom value? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either action class or `java script executor` to click

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

el = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('mycssselector')[0]
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).click().perform()
```

OR

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
```

OR

Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"mycssselector"))).click()
```

import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try selecting the element before the zoom, then use `execute_script` again to click the element.

```py
driver.get(url)
el = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('mycssselector')[0]
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='85%'")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
el.click()
```